# Trouble using if is() addClass()/removeClass()

Tags: jquery, if-statement, addclass, removeclass

I'm trying to make a sliding element toggle by animating it's alignment and adding/removing classes instead of just using the .toggle() function.

Unfortunatly my code doesn't feel like removing or adding any classes since I added the

```
if

$(document).ready(function() {  
    $(".slide-img-4").click(function(){
   if ("#slide4").is("mright") {
     $("#slide4").animate({ left: -610 }, "normal");
         $("#slide4").removeClass("mright");
        }
       else {
         $("#slide4").animate({ left: 610 }, "normal");
         $("#slide4").addClass("mright");
       };
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change `if ("$slide4").is("mright")` to `if ($('#slide4').hasClass('mright'))`

Answer (score 1):

The syntax for the `if` statement is not valid; the condition must have parentheses around it. Additionally, `"$slide4".is("mright")` would get a runtime error; strings have no `is` method. You probably meant to select `#slide4` as a jQuery object first:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".slide-img-4").click(function () {
        if($("#slide4").is("mright")) {
            $("#slide4").animate({
                left: -610
            }, "normal");
            $("#slide4").removeClass("mright");
        } else {
            $("#slide4").animate({
                left: 610
            }, "normal");
            $("#slide4").addClass("mright");
        };
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you're missing the period for the class mright.

```
if (("#slide4").is(".mright")) {
```

I'm not so sure that would work. You might want to try.

```
if (("#slide4").hasClass("mright")) {
```

Comment: I forgot the parentheses for the if statements, duh.